# Apache, catalina keeps saying stackoverflow

Tags: apache, tomcat, catalina

```html
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [] due to a StackOverflowError. Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was [org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector->org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodableVector->org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2104)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2048)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1994)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1964)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1917)
...
```

I am new to the Spring framework.

Here is the error message. Sometimes it can run while after stopping the project and re-run it, these messages are shown (but if I leave the IDE along for 5-10 mins, it can be run without errors).

What exactly is happening here? I am using the newest IDEA and Tomcat 8.

Comment: What exact version of Tomcat? What version of BouncyCastle?

Comment: Hi Christopher. Thanks for your reply. I am using Tomcat8.5.35 and 9.0.13. Both have this problem. The BC version is 1.47.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The reason is I was using a different version of Tomcat, version 8, while somehow the code is using version 7.
I am using macOS Mojave. On Windows, the code can be run via different versions, however, it seems that on macOS the version matters.